# pyHook for Mac; catching keystrokes outside of the application

Tags: python, keystroke

Is there a Mac alternative to the Windows Python extension, pyHook? I need to catch keystrokes outside of the python app; In any other software.

I've googled like hell an haven't found anything.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, No

This extenstion was designed specifically for windows

> System Requirements

```
Windows 2000 or later (low-level hooks are not supported in earlier versions of Windows)
Python 2.4 or later
PyWin32 (formerly known as win32all extensions)
```

Source: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/pyhook/index.php?title=Main_Page